# PHP facebook how to replace story_tags with story line?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, replace

i have following story "**Another Feed shared Non-Profits on Facebook's photo.**" and i want to replace its tags with links.

facebook api data story and story_tags

```
                    [story] => Another Feed shared Non-Profits on Facebook's photo.
                    [story_tags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1.7153566624E+14
                                            [name] => Another Feed
                                            [offset] => 0
                                            [length] => 12
                                            [type] => page
                                        )

                                )

                            [20] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 41130665917
                                            [name] => Non-Profits on Facebook
                                            [offset] => 20
                                            [length] => 23
                                            [type] => page
                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

if i replace the story tags with str_ireplace, then there is chance that two different tags can have same name, so it would not play well.

if i replace it with substr_replace(...), then after replace the length of story gets more then it was, so new tags wont work well together with it.

what would be best way to replace story tags with story line? im sure people already done it, but cant find it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here at my implementation:

```
  public function mapMentions($message, $tags) {
    if (empty($tags)) {
      return $message;
    }

    $offsetBuffer = 0;

    foreach (json_decode($tags, true) as $tag) {
      $link = $this->Html->link($tag['name'], $tag['link'], ['target' => '_blank']);
      $message = substr_replace($message, $link, $tag['offset'] + $offsetBuffer, $tag['length']);
      $offsetBuffer += (strlen($link) - $tag['length']);
    }

    return $message;
  }
```

1. First, you need the length of the generated link (graph.facebook.com/ID)
2. Now, you need to save the the difference between old length and new link length to a temp variable (in my case "offsetBuffer").
3. In the loop append the offsetBuffer to the old offset.

Voila! ;)